# ChatzrOS Kodshecha

Tags: chanuka, tefilla

In Al Hanissim we say:

**Vhidliku Neiros Bchatzros Kodshecha**

Why in do we use the Plural form, was there more than one Chatzer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various gradations of holiness within the Beis Hamikdash complex (listed in the Mishnah, Kelim 1:8ff) are each generally referred to in Tanach as a chatzer. The expression חצרות קדשך is borrowed from Isaiah 62:9 (בחצרות קדשי), referring to Jerusalem as a whole. And then we find, among others:

- חצר החדשה ("the new courtyard," II Chron. 20:5; this is identified as the Har Habayis (Rashi to Zevachim 32b) or the Ezras Nashim (Rambam, Hil. Bias Mikdash 3:6))
- חצר הגדולה ("the great courtyard") and חצר בית ה' הפנימית ("the inner courtyard of Hashem's house," both in I Kings 7:12), evidently referring to the Har Habayis and the Ezras Yisrael/Kohanim, respectively
- 'שתי חצרות בית ה (II Kings 21:5), probably referring to the same two (or maybe to the Ezras Yisrael/Kohanim and the Ezras Nashim)
- and numerous references to 'חצר בית ה and חצר החיצונה and חצר הפנימית in the books of Jeremiah and Ezekiel.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe's (zt"l) answer that I quoted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/where-did-they-light-the-menorah-after-they-won-the-war-with-the-greeks/4273#4273) says that indeed they lit lamps and candelabra throughout the entire complex (in all of these "courtyards") in order to show their gratitude to Hashem for the miracles of Chanukah.